# how to release unity webgl memory from asset bundle

Tags: unity, c#, assetbundle

I have stuck in a weird problem, in my Webgl project i am loading asset bundle frequently which is working fine but after unloading the asset bundle the memory is still not releasing. I am using `WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload` method to download and cache asset bundle data.

```
 IEnumerator DownloadAndCacheAB(string assetName)
    {
        // Wait for the Caching system to be ready
        while (!Caching.ready)
            yield return null;

        // Load the AssetBundle file from Cache if it exists with the same version or download and store it in the cache
        using (WWW www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload(finalUrl, 1))
        {

            yield return www;

            if (www.error != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("WWW download had an error:" + www.error);
            }

            AssetBundle bundle = www.assetBundle;

            if (assetName == "")
            {
                GameObject abObject = (GameObject)Instantiate(bundle.mainAsset, gameObject.transform.position, gameObject.transform.rotation);
                abObject.transform.parent = this.transform;
                SetTreeShaderSettings(abObject);
            }
            else
            {
                GameObject abObject = (GameObject)Instantiate(bundle.LoadAsset(assetName), gameObject.transform.position, gameObject.transform.rotation);
                abObject.transform.parent = this.transform;

            }

            // Unload the AssetBundles compressed contents to conserve memory
            bundle.Unload(false);

        } // memory is freed from the web stream (www.Dispose() gets called implicitly)
    }
```

And even calling GC Collect to remove data

```
public void RemoveBundleObject()
    {

        if (loadBundleRef != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(loadBundleRef);
        }
        if (this.gameObject.transform.childCount > 0)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject);
            System.GC.Collect();
        }

    }
```

but the problem is memory is not releasing, it keep going up when i again use/load asset bundle.

**Edit**: I found that using LoadFromCacheOrDownload function is not good so i have updated it with `UnityWebRequest` but the still problem persist.

Comment: Can you show us your code for loading the bundle and spawning the instance?

Comment: @DMGregory Yeah, i have update the code.

Comment: Hm, does UnloadUnusedAssets have any effect in this situation?

Comment: @DMGregory Yeah i have used this but it also not releasing the meomory but it definately generate a log that it used xyz number of assets.